# Allow Firestore database access only to Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating app with Firestore database only for Android platform. I want to restrict access to my Firestore database from Rest API.

Is there any way?

Comment: I really doubt this is feasible. Firestore is probably not even aware of what OS/platform is querying the database. It's probably only seeing an IP and a port, and discards the rest (or, if it sees it, you won't be able to add restrictions based on that).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in GCP there is option to restrict keys to specific platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  Firestore does not care where access comes from.  It could come from any client SDK, from any server SDK, or the REST API.

The only way to control access from a client SDK is to use security rules along with Firebase Authentication to limit access based on the user's identity.  Server SDK access is controlled using service accounts that are granted permission to read and write the database (and they bypass security rules altogether).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.